# stored procedure combining firstname with lastname

Tags: stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure and i wanted to combine both the firstname and lastname together as fullname and not sure how to do that.

U.FirstName,
U.LastName

I want to have FullName as FirstName and LastName.

Thanks for the help ahead.

Comment: Why do you need a stored procedure for this?  Does your database not allow for simple concatenation in select queries and/or views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amina, you're going to have to be very specific about which database this is for.  Stored procedures are implemented differently depending on the engine. If you're just doing this in a select you could do the following:

For Oracle you could do

```
select 
    U.FirstName || ' ' || U.LastName AS FullName
from
    USERS AS U
```

For MS-SQL Server (not sure on this)

```
select 
    [U].[FirstName] + ' ' + [U].[LastName] AS FullName
from
    USERS AS U
```

Again this is database dependent.

Comment: Thanks for the examples they have helped - but is there a special reason for []? I used the the same sample but without the []. Thanks again.

Comment: The [] are "formal" notation for SQL Server.  Its meant to explicitly delimit schema/table/column etc

Comment: select 
    [U].[FirstName] + ' ' + [U].[LastName] AS FullName
from
    USERS AS U

for MS SQL you can get a bug here. If one field is null you will obtain NULL as result of concatination

Answer (score 1):

If you want to concatenate the two fields, use `("foo" || "bar")` in an SQL statement to join the two strings. An example: `SELECT U.FirstName, U.LastName, (U.FirstName || " " || U.LastName) AS FullName FROM users as U`.

Comment: Thanks i used the + sign and it worked as well. 
U.FirstName + ' ' + U.LastName AS FullName. 

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the database you are using but something like:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, firstname + ' ' + lastname as fullname FROM User
```

should work

Comment: Thanks yes it did work for me i extracted what helped me from the posts above. Thanks again !